# Como cambiar el contenido de unas tablas al seleccionar opciones en multistate/tabla

Tags: php, javascript, html

Mi pregunta es la siguiente, tengo un codigo donde cargo los nombres de una base de datos en un desplegable:

```
<div class="pure-u-4-5">
<div class="pure-control-group">
<label id="idtype" for="multi-state">Type</label>
<?php 
selectDB("test_type", "", "id", "name", "SELECT * FROM batteries", 0, true);
?>
<br>
</div>
```

Por otro lado en una tabla donde cargo otros elementos de otras tablas relacionadas por ids:

```
<table id="tableTest" onclick="doWatch()" style="height: 5%" border="1" class="pure-table" >
<thead> <tr height="10px">
<td><a href="tests.php?sort=name">Related Tests</a></td>
</tr>
</thead> 
<tbody>

<?php
// Echo variables

 $sort = isset($_GET['sort']) ? $_GET['sort'] : 'id';

$conn = connectDB();

$query = "SELECT * FROM batteries b, batteries_tests bt, test_types tt "
"where b.id=bt.batteries_id AND bt.tests_id=tt.id";
debug_to_console($query);

$i=0;
 $results = mysql_query($query);
debug_to_console(mysql_error());

if (!$results) {

} else {
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
if ($i%2 != 0){
echo "<tr class='pure-table-odd' height='10px'>";
}
else{
echo "<tr height='10px'>";
}
?>
<td style="width: 20%;" align="center"><?php echo $row['name'] ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
$i++;
}
}
 mysql_close($conn);
?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Y a su vez tengo otra tabla donde tambien cargo mas elementos relacionados con la tabla anterior, pero no la adjunto por que con lo anterior creo que puedo explicar mi problema. Bien, querria saber como puedo hacer que aparezcan en mi consulta solo elementos relacionados con la opcion seleccionada en el multi state, Imagino que en el evento onchange() debo indicarle a la tabla que opcion he seleccionado pero no se como. **Quiero simplemente que si en el multi state selecciona por ejemplo: "platano", en la tabla aparezcan los tipos de platano que hay, y luego si en esa tabla seeleccionan "el de canarias" en la otra tabla saldran los colores de platanos de canarias que hay.** Añado tambien mi SelectDB donde pongo mi idea del onchange=\"hiddenOption();\

```
function selectDB($name, $type, $fieldValue, $tagValue, $query, $indexSelected, $enable) {

global $servername;
global $username;
global $password;
global $dbname;

$conn = connectDB();

$results = mysql_query($query);
if ($enable == true)
{
$data = "<SELECT class=\"input\" $type name=\"$name\" style=\"width: 300px\" onchange=\"hiddenOption();\" >";
}
else
{
$data = "<SELECT class=\"input\" $type name=\"$name\" style=\"width: 300px\" onchange=\"hiddenOption();\" disabled=\"disabled\" >";
}
echo $data;
    //debug_to_console($data);
    //debug_to_console("results: $results" );

$data = "<OPTION VALUE=\"0\" selected>All          ";
echo $data;

$i = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {

$data = "<OPTION VALUE=\"$row[$fieldValue]\"> $row[$tagValue]";

        //debug_to_console($indexSelected);
        //debug_to_console($i);

if ($i+1 == $indexSelected)
{
$data = "<OPTION VALUE=\"$row[$fieldValue]\" selected> $row[$tagValue]";

            //debug_to_console("data");
        }
        else
        {
            //debug_to_console("else");
        }
        echo $data;
        //debug_to_console($data);
        $i++;
    }
    echo "</SELECT>";

    mysql_close($conn);
}
```

Comment: si es que entendí bien tu pregunta, creo que necesitas utilizar ajax... como dices en el evento onchange, puedes llamar a una función javascript a la cual le pases el id de la opción seleccionada, teniendo esto; en la función deberías hacer una petición ajax, la cual apunte a un archivo php y realize la consulta que deseas en base al elemento seleccionado. luego en la respuesta de tu petion ajax tendras los datos que te devuelve dicha consulta, y ya podras maquetarla en en tu tabla html

Comment: No se como marcar tu comentario como respuesta pero es lo que hice. Osea segui intentandolo y al final lo logre con el metodo que tu dijiste, mediante una consulta ajax y recuperando la query. Un saludo y gracias

Comment: en realidad, lo que escribí fue un comentario.. dándote unas ideas, no escribí una respuesta como tal por que no tenia un código de ejemplo de lo mencionado, ahora si tienes algunas dificultades en tu código para esta parte hasmela saber en tu pregunta para ayudarte saludos

Comment: Hola @Criss, como dice Diego, debes poner tu comentario como respuesta para que te la pueda marcar como Aceptada. Aunque no hayas puesto código en tu comentario, al OP le ha servido para resolver el problema así que se puede considerar como una respuesta válida. No todas las respuestas buenas necesitan código obligatoriamente. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

si es que entendí bien tu pregunta, creo que necesitas utilizar ajax... como dices en el evento onchange, puedes llamar a una función javascript a la cual le pases el id de la opción seleccionada, teniendo esto; en la función deberías hacer una petición ajax, la cual apunte a un archivo php y realize la consulta que deseas en base al elemento seleccionado. luego en la respuesta de tu petion ajax tendras los datos que te devuelve dicha consulta, y ya podras maquetarla en en tu tabla html.